# htaccess rewrite friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hello I have the following structure `http://localhost/index.php?a=$var1&b=var2&c=$var3`

I would like to change it to that when someone goes to `http://localhost/$var1/$var2/$var3`
they get sent out to `http://localhost/index.php?a=$var1&b=var2&c=$var3`

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the appropriate place to the htaccess file in your document root.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?a=([^&]+)&b=([^&]+)&c=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Note that you're changing the relative URI base when you have the browser load a `/aaa/bbb/ccc` url as opposed to `/index.php`. So your links need to either be absolute URL's or you need a base tag in your page headers:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: what if i want to use that with 3 variables and also use another one with online argument a=var1 . do I need rewritecond ?